# How to make a connected app appear in the application switcher?

Tags: connected-apps

I want my connected app to show up in the application switch. According to the [pilot documentation](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_connected_apps.pdf), this should be possible by editing the "Start URL" field when managing connected apps. But when I go to manage my connected apps, there is no "Start URL" field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would create one (or more) Custom Web Tabs that link to your connected app. Then you create an Application that includes those tabs. Additionally you can set the home tab for the application, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the "Start URL" is only available in the Manage Apps view of Connected Apps, and not the Create view of the app.   Have you checked under the Manage Apps section?